# A better way to get ActiveRecord table's primary tables(belongs_to' tables) array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a table with many fields

```
[
    [ 0] "id",
    [ 1] "type",
    [ 2] "title",
    [ 3] "delivery_fee",
    [ 4] "price",
    [ 5] "starting_price",
    [ 6] "bid_increment",
    [ 7] "bid_expired_at",
    [ 8] "address",
    [ 9] "lat",
    [10] "lng",
    [11] "comments_count",
    [12] "clicks_count",
    [13] "detected_labels",
    [14] "deleted_at",
    [15] "created_at",
    [16] "updated_at",
    [17] "user_id",
    [18] "category_id",
    [19] "area_id",
    [20] "detected_labels_cn",
    [21] "tsv",
    [22] "tsv_full",
    [23] "data",
    [24] "stock_count",
    [25] "location_is_visible",
    [26] "make_offer_disabled_at",
    [27] "favorites_count",
    [28] "display_index"
]
```

What I want to do is:

get this table belongs to table names.

Followings is my solution:

```
GoodsItem.column_names.grep(/.*(_id)$/).map {|x| x[/(.*)_id/, 1] 
# Or
GoodsItem.column_names.map {|x| x.dup.sub!(/_id/, '') }.compact



[
    [0] "user",
    [1] "category",
    [2] "area"
]
```

This is not goods enough. because two almost same regexp match to get
this result or have to dup all string because I use `frozen String`

The question is:

1. Rails offer any methods to get this `belongs_to` lists?
2. If not, is there a better solution to resolve this than me?
   basically, I want one `method` to satisfy two condition:

   - fields must get ending with a `_id`
   - get the content matched except the part `_id`

Thanks.

Comment: Try `GoodsItem.reflections` - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html

Comment: GoodsItem.reflections return ``has_many`` and ``belongs_to``, what i want just ``belongs_to`` table names.

Comment: Did you take a look at that page? `GoodsItem.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to)` will do it.

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim, Yeah, it worked. GoodsItem.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name) get what i want, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A better answer:

```
GoodsItem.column_names.map {|x| x[/(.*)_id/, 1] }.compact
```

And more better answer:

```
GoodsItem.column_names.grep(/(.*)_id$/) { $1 }
```